# Windows 8 Performance Tools recommendations: Undo "remove from list"

Tags: windows-8, performance, control-panel

In the Windows 8 "Performance Information and Tools" Control Panel, there's an advanced section that shows detected performance issues.

If you click on one, it opens a small dialog summarizing the problem.  One of the buttons on this dialog is "Remove from list", which I now know persistently hides information on that performance issue in the future.

However, the purpose/behavior of this button is NOT CLEAR.  I was looking at the notification about programs slowing Windows startup, and the recommendation is to remove programs from the auto-start list.  In that context, I understood that the button would take me to my list of startup tasks so I could remove or disable some.  Of course it didn't.

How can I undo "Remove from list" / reset the hidden issues so that they appear again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and referred it to the Microsoft Community. After I had the problem, under Advanced Tools when I counted there were 9 items and I thought I had one less. Then came the reply from Microsoft Community that they also see only 9 items. Then I figured out, under the heading on top "Performance issues" now it says "No issues reported". May be when there are issues, it reports the issue there and when you click it, the dialog box with the option to remove that specific issue from the list appears. (Remove Item from list) Not to worry, when there is another issue it will show there, and the same dialog box will appear.